# How can I check the members of a ranked team?

Tags: league-of-legends

I just received a ghost invitation to join a ranked team.

Is there any way to see who are the members of that team?

Comment: In order to accept the invitation, you have to go to the the team page, the members should be listed there

Comment: I dont want accept before check the members and the last matches. So, i only can check the team member if i'm log LoL? Cant I check it in a website?

Comment: You arent accepting it by going to the teams profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When clicking on the invitation it will bring you to the team page where members are listed and you have to click a button that says accept.

You can also search ranked teams from the profile page and clicking on the tab ranked teams then using the search bar and type in the name of the team that sent the invitation.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access player's stats by various websites. OP.GG is a good website that checks MMR, player match history, and player champion history.